# C++ - How to find source of heap / stack corruption on program exit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, heap-memory, stack-memory, memory-corruption

I have a project which causes two assertion failures in succession, AFTER the 'main'-function is completed. This is very problematic because it doesn't show me the piece of code causing the problem.

I was able to narrow the problem down somewhat. With an empty main-function:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    return main(__argc,__argv);
}
```

everything is working just fine. However as soon as I use any class or function from a specific dll (which is part of the project), the problem starts occurring:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    Color col(255,0,0,255);
    col.r += 1;
    int r = HeapValidate(GetProcessHeap(),0,nullptr);
    std::cout<<r<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    return main(__argc,__argv);
}
```

the 'Color' class is part of that dll, but it's not the cause of the issue. 'HeapValidate' returns 1, which means the heap is valid according to the documentation.

The dll in question contains hundreds of thousands lines of code, which makes debugging even more difficult.

On a similar question, I found the suggestion to use WinDBG, but I'm not sure what to do with the result:

http://pastebin.com/zV27b51Z

It confirms that the issue is some sort of memory corruption, but I still don't know where it originates from.

Is there any way to reliably find the origin, or am I stuck using trial and error?

My OS is Windows 8.1, I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: The DLL might have a separate heap: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee175820(v=vs.85).aspx Also, look if that DLL does anything suspicious in its detachment code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Run the application under debugger and press Retry button in assertion messagebox. DebugBreak will be called and the debugger will take coltrol.

Comment: That doesn't work because the problem occurs AFTER the main-call has already returned. The debugger can't step in at that point anymore.

Comment: Please specify the exact program behavior. How did you find, that assertion failures took place?